# Why would I need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to select an image from the gallery

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-image

Hello I am trying to understand the difference in using `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` vs `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` when implementing code to select an image form the gallery or photos. I can understand why `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is used in some cases but I am curious if I am picking an image, wouldnt I just be reading? Why in most examples I found they `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` when selecting an image, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For getting a file from Gallery, you don't need any permission. You only need to start an Intent. 
If you want to read external storage you only need `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission

Comment: thank you for your response, would using write_extrernal_storage also includes the READ portion? I am curious why it works as well

Comment: No. `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is a very dangerous permission and android 6 and above user must explicitly grant it.

Answer (score -1):

I think because of some caching system in background, it needs write permission too.

just try each one separately and see the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that makes sense but if thats the case why can I use READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as well?